# "Это Вы даете - не ответ даже, а совет - проверять по словарю" - пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот написал такую фразу. *"Это не я, это Вы даете - не ответ даже, а совет - проверять такие вещи по словарю"*. Пунктуацию дал по наитию. Ну в конце точка, естественно. А остальное-то как?! Сложность в том, что конструкция "не ответ даже, а совет" строго говоря вводной не является, без неё фраза теряет смысл. Но её надо как-то обособить, иначе совсем не так воспринимается.

Или я фантазирую?
(+)
Добавлю, чтобы не было проблем в понимании смысла. Эта фраза эквивалентна другой, с инверсией: **"Это Вы - не ответ даже, а совет - проверять по словарю тут даете"**. Ну или любой другой, исключающей понимание как бессоюзного с раскрытием смысла во второй части.

Comment: ОК, спасибо. Но уж опечатку  Вы и сами могли.)) И если уж очень хотите сокращать мой ник, пишите *В-s*, это хоть понятно.

Comment: Странно смотрится "?" в заголовке после одного слова "пунктуация"... Выглядит похоже на реплику в чатах из одного только "?".

Answer (score 3):

Если б второго тире не было, всё было бы в норме:

"Это не я, это Вы даете - не ответ даже, а совет  проверять такие вещи по словарю". - Первое тире отделяет присоединительную конструкцию (правда, тогда основное предложение  неполное, с пропуском дополнения. Но ведь это ответ, диалог, вполне допустимо). Можно и запятой отделить, и многоточием.

"Это не я, это Вы даете - не ответ даже, а совет - проверять такие вещи по словарю". Эту пунктуацию тоже можно объяснить. Первое тире - начало присоединения, а второе - обособление несогласованного определения, выраженного инфинитивом, перед которым можно поставить "а именно".

А можно и без обособления вообще:  "Это не я, это Вы даете  не ответ, а совет  проверять такие вещи по словарю".(Но без "даже".) Если есть ДАЖЕ, то это явно присоединение.

Answer (score 2):

Пусть эта конструкция даже и не выглядит как вводная — поставьте вместо второго тире двоеточие. Оно и по-любому правильнее.

Comment: А на каком основании двоеточие-то? Тире знак весьма вольный, где автор захочет, там и поставит (ну почти), а двоеточие требует к себе весьма строгого отношения. Я не вижу тут причин для оного.

Comment: А почему нет причин? Есть причина: вторая часть бессоюзного предл. раскрывает смысл первой: ...не ответ даже, а совет(какой совет?):проверять такие вещи по словарю

Comment: Ой... А где вы тут увидели раскрытие смысла, да еще бессоюзное сложное? Тут совсем другая грамматика. "Это вы даете совет проверять по словарю". Ну какое тут двоеточие?! Теперь вместо дополнения "совет" ставим конструкцию "не совет, а ответ" - тоже некое дополнение, только чуть более хитро построенное. Я ж и говорил, что смысл меняется, если начинать со знаками экспериментировать. С таким же успехом можно подлежащее заменить: "Не ответ а совет проверять пол словарю тут вами даётся" - тот же случай в общем-то, никаких бессоюзных сложных.

Comment: Я про то, что причину поставить двоеточие тоже можно найти, была бы воля автора: "Это не я, это Вы даете - не ответ даже, а совет: (нужно) проверять такие вещи по словарю". Другое дело, что Вы вкладываете несколько другой смысл, здесь автор хозяин. И Вашу конструкцию с двумя тире можно объяснить. Сейчас попробую.